# Is it possible to access a framework's information from an application's Info.plist?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to add some keys to an xcconfig file within my framework so the user doesn't have to manually add them to their app's Info.plist. For example, I have a URL that needs to be added to the app's Info.plist as

```
<key>frameworkURL</key>
<string>https://www.example.com</string>
```

but I would like to have this URL defined already within my framework so the user could just do

```
<key>frameworkURL</key>
<string>$(FRAMEWORK_URL)</string>
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, so if anyone knows about another possibility, I would also be very grateful